# How to copy char array to char array using int in C

Tags: c, arrays

As an academic task I need to copy char array to char array using integer variable to copy 4 chars at once in every iteration. I'm aware that there are specialised functions to do that, it's just the matter of exercise. I tried as below:

```
char source[SIZE];
//populate chars in source
char dest[SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < (SIZE + 3) / 4; i++)
{
    int number = *(int*)(source + 4 * i);
    *(dest + 4 * i) = (int)number;
}
```

The result is that only every fourth element is properly copied so I suppose I mixed something up with pointers. How should I correct it?

Comment: CUDA is not C. Completely different languages! And you should provide a [mcve]. The pointer-cast looks very suspicious it invokes undefined behaviour..

Comment: As I stated - I mentioned CUDA only to give a context. But I'm asking about pure C. BTW. C is principal language to program CUDA.

Comment: @Olaf the q shows C code and asks about that C code -> rolled back

Comment: CUDA is C++ based, which is not C either! You should do your homework before asking. But as you ask about C, fine. Just don't spam the CUDA tag then! And in C it is definitively undefined behaviour.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Instead of rollback, you should have change the CUDA tag to C. Either way, they are distinct languages, OP is wrongly assuming CUDA is C based. This is wrong.

Comment: Stanward, please, could you edit your question only asking specifically what you need to avoid more discussions and also people could help you :)?

Comment: Any reason you don't use `memcpy` or `int` arrays? Both will likely result in highly optimised copy loops.

Comment: In Standard C nothing like this can ever work because of the strict aliasing rule. If the question is actually about CUDA (which may not have the strict aliasing rule - IDK) then it should be tagged as such

Comment: @M.M. even "Standard C" doesn't say it "cannot work". It says it's *undefined*. Although this is a huge red flag for any code not specifically written for a particular implementation, this still doesn't guarantee failure. It's arguably "worse": Given the obvious errors are fixed, this method will quite likely work with most implementations for the `x86` platform...

Comment: @FelixPalmen I include "undefined" in "doesn't work"

Comment: @M.M If this was the case, C would be a much "easier" language. There's a reason many (especially more recent) languages don't leave anything *undefined*.

Answer (score 2):

The writing part is wrong, you write to

```
*(dest + 4 * i)
```

and as `dest` is a pointer to `char`, the type of this expression still is `char`. The cast for `number` is **not** needed, it is already an `int`. So the "correct" line would be:

```
*(int *)(dest + 4 * i) = number;
```

I write "correct" in quotes because according to standard C, aliasing pointers with a different type is not allowed. As an exception, a `char` pointer may alias any other pointer, but **here you do it the other way around**, this is by no means guaranteed to work as expected.

Also note that what you do is unnecessarily complicated, you could just alias an `int *` to the start of your array and increment that pointer by one to get the next `int`, or use simple indexers. It could look as simple as:

```
char source[SIZE];
//populate chars in source
char dest[SIZE];

int *srcptr = (int *)source;
int *dstptr = (int *)dst;
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE / sizeof(int); ++i)
{
    dstptr[i] = srcptr[i];
}
```

---

Be aware this is not at all portable: It depends on some properties like the machine not requiring alignment for `int`, not using any padding bits, etc.

And finally, a little example of how this could go wrong even when these assumptions are met, as e.g. on `x86`:

```
char source[SIZE];
char dest[SIZE];

source[0] = 'a';
dest[0] = 'b';

int *srcptr = (int *)source;
int *dstptr = (int *)dst;

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE / sizeof(int); ++i)
{
    dstptr[i] = srcptr[i];
}

printf("%c\n", dest[0]); // <- might output 'b'
```

This is a *stupid* example for simplicity, but an aggressively optimizing compiler might indeed optimize away the final read from `dest[0]` because it "knows" from the lines above it holds the value `'b'`. Because pointers to a different type are not *allowed* to alias the array, the logic is, nothing in this program *could possibly alias*. Not so obvious in this stupid example, but with more complex programs, there might be really no way for the compiler to determine whether pointers alias each other, so the strict aliasing rule makes the decision easier on which optimization is allowed.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks, it's what I meant! I think that only one slight modification on stop condition should be applied as it doesn't affect last couple of chars in case of SIZE is not divisible by sizeof(int). Possible modification:
(SIZE + sizeof(int) -1)/ sizeof(int)

Comment: @stanwar very bad idea, this way wou will read (and write!) beyond the bounds of your arrays. Do the last few bytes one-by-one in ANY case and be aware that aliasing pointers is strictly speaking undefined behavior and could break.

Comment: for real-world code, just use `memcpy()`, this is already optimized **and safe to use**

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a learning assignment, you should submit an explanation that what you were requested to achieve can't be done in C without invoking undefined behaviour.

At least one of the reason this invokes undefined behaviour is because some machine have alignment restrictions which vary by types. For example, a machine could allow a char to be found at any address, but require that 32-bit ints be located at addresses divisible by 4. On such a machine, `char* p = ...; *((uint32_t*)p)` could result in an alignment fault.

(Even on machines that have no alignment restrictions for 32-bit ints, reading unaligned ints can be slower than reading aligned ints.)

At best, you could write code that works using specific settings of specific versions of specific compilers for specific machines. You'd be sitting on a time bomb.

---

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// XXX Relies on undefined behaviour.
void* my_memcpy(void* dst, const void* src, size_t n) {
   uint32_t*       dst_uint32_ptr = (uint32_t*)dst;
   const uint32_t* src_uint32_ptr = (const uint32_t*)src;
   for (; n>4; n-=4) { *(dst_uint32_ptr++) = *(src_uint32_ptr++); }

   char*       dst_char_ptr = (char*)dst_uint32_ptr;
   const char* src_char_ptr = (const char*)src_uint32_ptr;
   while (n--) { *(dst_char_ptr++) = *(src_char_ptr++); }

   return dst;
}

int main(void) {
   const char* orig = "Hello, world.";
   size_t len = strlen(orig)+1;

   char* copy = malloc(len);
   my_memcpy(copy, orig, len);

   printf("%s\n", copy);
   free(copy);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic --std=c99 -o a a.c && a
Hello, world.
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to cast the dest pointer

```
 *(int *)(dest + 4 * i) = number;
```

and thath is the reason for the problem as you write only one byte.

Comment: There is a second problem: `i < (SIZE + 3) / 4` causes reads past the end of the buffer.